# Is it possible to rewrite $\frac{m\cdot \ln2}{\frac{n(1-(1-p)^r)}{p}}$ as $\frac{p\cdot \ln2}{(1-(1-p)^r)\frac{n}{m}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is this rewriting possible? If so, how?

$$\frac{m\cdot \ln2}{\dfrac{n(1-(1-p)^r)}{p}} = \frac{p\cdot \ln2}{(1-(1-p)^r)\dfrac{n}{m}}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you are multiplying $n/m $ by $(1-(1-p)^r)$, then its the same thing. It is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed it is. To understand this, send terms of both m and p to the numerator, on both sides, and the equation will then look exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

One way to proceed is to factor out $p$ from denominator & try to cancel out with $p$ in numerator...but that will make it look messy . 
Otherwise, $$(p.m.ln2)/(n(1-(1-p)^r)$$ is the simplest form.